# Adding Google Calendar entry without using setUserCredentials

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth, google-apps

I am following the example provided by Google for Market place app at

http://code.google.com/googleapps/marketplace/tutorial_dotnet.html

I got the google authentication working as in the example ,
My next task is to add a entry to Google calendar. I found following code for that, and it is also working fine

```
CalendarService service = new CalendarService(APPLICATION_NAME);


            service.setUserCredentials(vUserName, vPassword);

            Google.GData.Calendar.EventEntry entry = new Google.GData.Calendar.EventEntry();

            // Set the title and content of the entry.
            entry.Title.Text = title;
            entry.Content.Content = contents;

            // Set a location for the event.
            Where eventLocation = new Where();
            eventLocation.ValueString = location;
            entry.Locations.Add(eventLocation);

            When eventTime = new When(startTime, endTime);
            entry.Times.Add(eventTime);

            Uri postUri = new Uri("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full");

            // Send the request and receive the response:
            AtomEntry insertedEntry = service.Insert(postUri, entry);
```

The problem i have is the following line, If i give my username and password it will work

```
service.setUserCredentials(vUserName, vPassword);
```

i have authenticated the user as in google example. So I don’t know the username and password of other users login to my site using their gmail.

How do i add a calender entry with the information i have?

I have seen several examples with RequestFactory authenticating the user. but couldn't find  complete example that I can use

Comment: Is there a way to get authToken?

Answer (score 1):

1. you will need to create a .pfx cert file and upload it to google and place it on your server.
2. create your AuthSubRequest URL

   ```
   <asp:HyperLink ID="GotoAuthSubLink" runat="server"/>
   GotoAuthSubLink.Text = "Login to your Google Account"; 
   GotoAuthSubLink.NavigateUrl = AuthSubUtil.getRequestUrl("(return url)http://www.example.com/RetrieveToken", "https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/", false, true);
   ```
3. after the person clicks on your auth link they are returned to your return url. get your session token as follows

   ```
   String sessionToken = ""; //Save this for making your calls.
   String certFile = "D:\\websites\\yourwebsite.com\\google.pfx";
   String result = GetAuthSubSessionToken(Request["token"]);

   protected AsymmetricAlgorithm GetRsaKey()
   {
       X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(certFile, ""); 
       RSACryptoServiceProvider privateKey = cert.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
       return privateKey;
   }

   public string GetAuthSubSessionToken(string singleUseToken)
   {
       string gatStr = "";
       try
       {
           AsymmetricAlgorithm rsaKey = GetRsaKey();
           try
           {
               sessionToken = AuthSubUtil.exchangeForSessionToken(singleUseToken, rsaKey).ToString();
               gatStr = "Session Token = " + SessionToken;
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               gatStr = "Error: I appears that the Google authentication server is experiencing an error. Try the authorizaton link again in a few minutes. <a href=\""
                        + rtnUrl + "\" title=\"" + e.Message + "\">continue</a>";
           }
       }
       catch (Exception E)
       {
           gatStr = "Error: rsa " + E.Message + E.StackTrace;
       }
       return gatStr;
   }
   ```
4. save the session token and use CreateCalendarService in subsequent calls to create your calendar service.

   ```
   public CalendarService CreateCalendarService()
   {
       GAuthSubRequestFactory authFactory = new GAuthSubRequestFactory("cl", "YourName-calendarApp-1");
       authFactory.Token = sessionToken;
       authFactory.PrivateKey = GetRsaKey();
       CalendarService cs = new CalendarService(authFactory.ApplicationName);
       cs.RequestFactory = authFactory;
       return cs;
   }
   ```